# How to parse Python output in console using Java

Tags: java, python

I have a Python program like this:

```
import time
while True:
    print("Python")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then I converted the `.py` file to `.exe` file using Pyinstaller using

`pyinstaller -y -F  "C:/test.py"`

I want to read the live output by Python in the console window, using Java.

I think, I need to run the `.exe` file using Java, and save the output.

Comment: Why/Where use Java in all of this ?

Comment: Presumably this is just a toy to play around with processes, as I can't think of any reason why this example would exist. There are many ways of doing this. Who is responsible for starting the python script? The java program or the user of the OS?

Comment: Java program starts the exe file created  from python

Comment: This is not a toy project. My client needs this program in Java, and I have no clue, where to start. I was hoping, I would get some ideas or Leeds that I can follow